# How to integrate 3rd party app's urls into my url structure?

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to use 3rd party app such as `imagestore`.
Default `imagestore url config` works like `site.com/gallery/(album, image, tag)`. I want to change urls to `site.com/username/(album, image, tag)` (i.e., remove `gallery`), but do not know how to do it, because there is `namespace='imagestore'`, which `imagestore` uses internaly.

```
# core urls
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='base.html'), name="home"),
    url(r'^gallery/', include('imagestore.urls', namespace='imagestore')),
    url(r'^(?P<user_url>[\w.-]+)/', include('profiles.urls', namespace='profiles_username')),
]

# profiles.urls
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.profiles_home, name='profiles_home'),
]

# piece of imagestore urls
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', AlbumListView.as_view(), name='index'),

    url(r'^album/add/$', CreateAlbum.as_view(), name='create-album'),
    url(r'^album/(?P<album_id>\d+)/$', ImageListView.as_view(), name='album'),
    url(r'^album/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', UpdateAlbum.as_view(), name='update-album'),
    url(r'^album/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', DeleteAlbum.as_view(), name='delete-album'),

    url(r'^tag/(?P<tag>[^/]+)/$', ImageListView.as_view(), name='tag'),

    url(r'^user/(?P<username>\w+)/albums/', AlbumListView.as_view(), name='user'),
    url(r'^user/(?P<username>\w+)/$', ImageListView.as_view(), name='user-images'),

    url(r'^upload/$', CreateImage.as_view(), name='upload'),
]
```

As I understand, I need somehow to remove `url(r'^gallery/', include('imagestore.urls', namespace='imagestore')),`, add to `profiles.urls` such part as `include('imagestore.urls')`, but at the same time somehow to keep `namespace='imagestore'`.

I tried this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.profiles_home, name='profiles_home'),
    url(r'', include('imagestore.urls', namespace='imagestore')),
]
```

but

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: 'imagestore' is not a registered namespace
```

EDIT:
As I tried 2 solutions below and they did not work, my guess is that the problem is due to the parameter `<user_url>` in

```
url(r'^(?P<user_url>[\w.-]+)/', include('imagestore.urls', namespace='imagestore')),
```

which `imagestore` can not handle, because any other names, such as `r'^lalala/` works. Is there anyway how to `hide` this parameter for `imagestore`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
# core urls
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='base.html'), name="home"),
    url(r'^(?P<user_url>[\w.-]+)/', include('profiles.urls', namespace='profiles_username')),
    url(r'^[\w.-]+/', include('imagestore.urls', namespace='imagestore')),
]
```

i.e. `r'^(?P<user_url>[\w.-]+)/',` changed to `r'^[\w.-]+/',`. `<user_url>` sends to `imagestore` a variable, which cannot be handled.

Comment: Glad you found the solution to your problem on your own. BTW, it is perfectly fine to mark your own answer as correct!

Answer (score 0):

If you include `imagestore.urls` with namespace `imagestore` in `profiles.urls` with namespace `profiles`, you create a nested namespace `profiles:imagestore`.

Try including `imagestore.urls` in your core urlpatterns, with the same base URL as `profiles.urls`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='base.html'), name="home"),
    url(r'^(?P<user_url>[\w.-]+)/', include('imagestore.urls', namespace='imagestore')),
    url(r'^(?P<user_url>[\w.-]+)/', include('profiles.urls', namespace='profiles_username')),
]
```

Comment: `NoReverseMatch at /test_user_acc/album/add/` and 
`Reverse for 'upload' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<user_url>[\\w.-]+)/upload/$']` And for some reason there is one more backslash in [\\w.-]

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace `/gallery/` with `/<someusername>/`? If so, try this:

```
#core urls
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='base.html'), name="home"),
    url(r'^(?P<user_url>[\w.-]+)/', include('profiles.urls', namespace='profiles_username')),
    url(r'^(?P<user_url>[\w.-]+)/', include('imagestore.urls', namespace='imagestore')),
]
```

Leave your `profiles.urls` as before. That way, when an url is requested Django will first check `profiles.urls`, if the path is just a username, there will be a match and it will try to get you this user's page. Otherwise Django will check the next option to see if there's a match and it'll load `imagestore.urls`

Comment: Currently no difference between your proposition and Daniel's one - the same error which you can find at the comment above

Comment: Just to clarify - is the username you are testing with really `test_user_acc`? If so, you have to add underscore to url settings. Are you able to visit the userpage?

Comment: yes, I use test_user_acc. Site is under development :) I have few test accs as test_user_acc, test_user_acc2, etc. I am able to visit userpage. `[\w]` already includes underscore - `\w
Matches any alphanumeric character; this is equivalent to the class [a-zA-Z0-9_].` from doc https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/regex.html